# Remove Axis ticks in pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I use the code below to create a stacked bar chart. The chart is created correctly but I would like to remove the small lines near each label (see in the picture below). I would like to have the numbers but without the small lines. Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass[border=5mm] {standalone}\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotstableread{
    T myCol
    1000 0.3
    10000 0.4
    }
    {\loadedtable}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,   % Stacked horizontal bars
    ymin=0,         % Start x axis at 0
    xtick=data,     % Use as many tick labels as y coordinates
    xticklabels from table={\loadedtable}{T},  % Get the labels from the Label column of the \datatable
    ]
    \addplot [fill=blue] table [y=myCol, meta=T,x expr=\coordindex] {\loadedtable}; 

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Just add `ytick=\empty`. Please notice that practically no one can compile your example since you load a data file others won't have.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, thanks! That removed both the number and the small lines. I'm interested in keeping the numbers but removing the small lines.

Comment: Then use e.g. `ytick style={draw=none},`. Or use `ytick style={/pgfplots/major tick length=0pt},`.

Comment: Yes, that solved it, many many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ytick style={draw=none}` or `ytick style={/pgfplots/major tick length=0pt}` to get

```
\documentclass[border=5mm] {standalone}\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotstableread{
    T myCol
    1000 0.3
    10000 0.4
    }
    {\loadedtable}
\begin{axis}[ytick style={draw=none},
    %ytick style={/pgfplots/major tick length=0pt},%<-alternative
    ybar stacked,   % Stacked horizontal bars
    ymin=0,         % Start x axis at 0
    xtick=data,     % Use as many tick labels as y coordinates
    xticklabels from table={\loadedtable}{T},  % Get the labels from the Label column of the \datatable
    ]
    \addplot [fill=blue] table [y=myCol, meta=T,x expr=\coordindex] {\loadedtable}; 

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]